# Compiling code that is both PIC and PIE with external symbols

Tags: c, gcc, arm, compiler-optimization, ld

I am trying to compile a code that will compile to a position independent piece of binary. The code I am trying to compile put a reference to function in a global memory address, for example:

```c
// main.c
extern int (**symbol_to_write_function_pointer_to)();
int some_function();

int main(void)
{
    *symbol_to_write_function_pointer_to = &some_function;
    return 0;
}

int some_function()
{
    return 1;
}
```

In order to determine the address of `symbol_to_write_function_pointer_to` I tried using the following ld script:

```
# symbols.txt
symbol_to_write_function_pointer_to = 0x00001000;
```

And I am building the code with `arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc`:

```
arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc main.c -Os -nostdlib -nolibc -nodefaultlibs -nostartfiles -march=armv5tej -mcpu="arm926ej-s" -mthumb -o main -Wl,-R,symbols.txt -Wl,-e,main -Wl,-exclude-libs,All -Wl,--section-start=.text=0xffff0000
```

The issue is that looking at the disassembly, the address of `some_function` is compiled as an absolute address instead of being position independent (generated with `arm-linux-gnueabi-objdump -d main`)
:

```
ffff0000:   4b02        ldr r3, [pc, #8]    ; (ffff000c <main+0xc>)
ffff0002:   4a03        ldr r2, [pc, #12]   ; (ffff0010 <main+0x10>)
ffff0004:   681b        ldr r3, [r3, #0]
ffff0006:   2000        movs    r0, #0
ffff0008:   601a        str r2, [r3, #0]
ffff000a:   4770        bx  lr
ffff000c:   00001000    .word   0x00001000
ffff0010:   ffff0015    .word   0xffff0015

ffff0014 <some_funcion>:
ffff0014:   2001        movs    r0, #1
ffff0016:   4770        bx  lr
```

I tried using the `-fpic` flag, which resulted in trying to get the addresses from a totally different place (I assume it is the .got section)

```
ffff0000 <main>:
ffff0000:   4b04        ldr r3, [pc, #16]   ; (ffff0014 <main+0x14>)
ffff0002:   4a05        ldr r2, [pc, #20]   ; (ffff0018 <main+0x18>)
ffff0004:   447b        add r3, pc
ffff0006:   589a        ldr r2, [r3, r2]
ffff0008:   4904        ldr r1, [pc, #16]   ; (ffff001c <main+0x1c>)
ffff000a:   6812        ldr r2, [r2, #0]
ffff000c:   585b        ldr r3, [r3, r1]
ffff000e:   2000        movs    r0, #0
ffff0010:   6013        str r3, [r2, #0]
ffff0012:   4770        bx  lr
ffff0014:   0001001c    .word   0x0001001c
ffff0018:   00000010    .word   0x00000010
ffff001c:   0000000c    .word   0x0000000c

ffff0020 <some_funcion>:
ffff0020:   2001        movs    r0, #1
ffff0022:   4770        bx  lr
```

Using the `-fpie` flag was better - the `some_function` address was loaded dynamically but `symbol_to_write_function_pointer_to` was still referenced from the .got:

```
ffff0000 <main>:
ffff0000:   4b04        ldr r3, [pc, #16]   ; (ffff0014 <main+0x14>)
ffff0002:   4a05        ldr r2, [pc, #20]   ; (ffff0018 <main+0x18>)
ffff0004:   447b        add r3, pc
ffff0006:   589b        ldr r3, [r3, r2]
ffff0008:   4a04        ldr r2, [pc, #16]   ; (ffff001c <main+0x1c>)
ffff000a:   681b        ldr r3, [r3, #0]
ffff000c:   447a        add r2, pc
ffff000e:   2000        movs    r0, #0
ffff0010:   601a        str r2, [r3, #0]
ffff0012:   4770        bx  lr
ffff0014:   0001001c    .word   0x0001001c
ffff0018:   0000000c    .word   0x0000000c
ffff001c:   00000011    .word   0x00000011

ffff0020 <some_funcion>:
ffff0020:   2001        movs    r0, #1
ffff0022:   4770        bx  lr
```

Is there any way to take the address of `symbol_to_write_function_pointer_to` like in the first example (plain data in the .text section) and take the address of `some_funcion` by its offset in the text section and not with the .got?

The only way I found is probably the ugliest - with assembly:

```c
int main(void)
{
    int (**reference)();
    asm volatile (
        ".extern symbol_to_write_function_pointer_to\n\t"
        "LDR %0, =symbol_to_write_function_pointer_to\n\t" : "=r"(reference)
    );
    *reference = &some_funcion;
    return 0;
}
```

Which compiles to:

```
ffff0000 <main>:
ffff0000:   4b03        ldr r3, [pc, #12]   ; (ffff0010 <main+0x10>)
ffff0002:   4a02        ldr r2, [pc, #8]    ; (ffff000c <main+0xc>)
ffff0004:   2000        movs    r0, #0
ffff0006:   447a        add r2, pc
ffff0008:   601a        str r2, [r3, #0]
ffff000a:   4770        bx  lr
ffff000c:   0000000b    .word   0x0000000b
ffff0010:   00001000    .word   0x00001000

ffff0014 <some_funcion>:
ffff0014:   2001        movs    r0, #1
ffff0016:   4770        bx  lr
```

But I really want to believe that there is a better solution

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `-fPIC` has to go through the GOT because symbol interposition is possible (e.g. `LD_PRELOAD`) unless you set the ELF visibility to `hidden`.   Looking at GCC's `-S` asm output (rather than disassembly) would give more info on the meaning of what it's doing.  If you want to put your code in a shared library, you almost certainly should be compiling with `-fPIC`.

Comment: `LDR %0, =symbol_to_write_function_pointer_to` will load an absolute address from a nearby literal pool, so I don't think that can be position-independent for the `symbol_to_write_function_pointer_to` address.  At best it'll have a text relocation, at worst it'll be the wrong address.

Comment: `LDR %0, =symbol_to_write_function_pointer_to` loads the absolute address of `symbol_to_write_function_pointer_to` which is exactly what I want, I will add the objdump output

Comment: You said in the title you wanted PIE / PIC compatible code.  Having an absolute address mixed in with the machine code (in a literal pool between functions) isn't position-independent, it requires a runtime relocation in the `.text` section.  https://godbolt.org/z/dqbM8x64d shows GCC `-O2 -fPIE` loading a relative displacement from a literal pool and adding `pc` to it, for PC-relative addressing.

Comment: Sorry that I probably didn't explain it well - I want my code to be position independent (so the reference to `some_function` will be PC relative (and without got) but I want to access global variables without PC dependency

Comment: Oh, then yeah you probably need inline asm, unless `-fno-pie` happens to use only relative jumps/calls anyway because that's the what's efficient on ARM.

Comment: position independent does mean the functions/code are relative.  the data goes through the got to change its position.

Comment: the function pointer is a variable and such its location is found through the got.  finding the address of a function that is in position independent code would require math relative to the program counter.  a combination of the linker and compiler would be needed to pull that off.  Or I guess you could get the address as linked and know the starting address and do math of where you actually put the code.  depends on the tools and instruction set.  with arm could go either way.

Comment: yes, a simpler experiment it does show the address is put in the .got. and this is a bit tricky because I would expect when you move the data you would go through that table and simply add(/subtract) the offset.  but this kind of messes that up.  if you move the code you technically know where you moved it, you know the offset and can do the math.  would expect something easier for this use case, would expect the tools to do the work.  so this does not make sense....yet....